# Добавление переносов в строке в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//JQ
var message = $(".chat_textarea").val();
var html = '<div class="chat_mess">'+message+'</div>';
$(".dialog").append(html);
```

Есть JQ код, читаю содержимое textarea, и вывожу его в определенный DIV. Проблема в том, что в textarea я могу написать тест с переносами строк, и даже в консоль он выводится с переносами, а вот при от рисовки его на экране - все в одну строку

Подскажите, как добавить переносы?

p.s.

```
//input - ввожу:
строка1
строка2

//div
строка1строка2
```

Comment: Вставляйте в присваиваемый HTML тег `<br>`, или устанавливайте элементу CSS-свойство `white-space` с наиболее подходящим значением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var message = $("#chat_textarea").val();
  var html = '<div class="chat_mess">' + message + '</div>';
  $("#dialogue").append(html);
});
```

```css
.chat_mess {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="chat_textarea">
</textarea>
<button> Send! </button>
<div id="dialogue">
</div>
```

Comment: Помогло! white-space: pre-line; в этом стиле было дело

Answer (score 2):

Решение с заменой переносов на теги `<br>`:

```js
var entityMap = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  '/': '&#x2F;',
  '`': '&#x60;',
  '=': '&#x3D;'
};

function escapeHtml(string) {
  return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, function(s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}

function nl2br(str) {
  var breakTag = '<br />';
  return String(str).replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}

$('.send_btn').click(() => {
  var message = escapeHtml($(".chat").val());
  var html = '<div class="mess">' + nl2br(message) + '</div>';
  $(".dialog").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class=chat>
 Line 1
 Line 2
 <script>alert('XSS корректно экранирован')</script>
</textarea>
<button class=send_btn>Send</button>

<div class=dialog></div>
```

Comment: Жаль что 2 решения за Акцептить нельзя, но если решать без CSS, решение отличное